# How segue works only with some specified buttons

Tags: swift, xcode, button, segue, pass-data

I'm doing a project by using Xcode. I have four buttons, two of them are to pass data between views, and want the other two for just jumping to another view without passing any data. The first two perform very well, pass data to another view. But when I click the rest two, the app crashes by saying:

> "2017-10-30 23:08:11.970500-0400 xxx[2557:65602] Could not cast value
>   of type 'xxx.goalInfoViewController' (0x107f01580) to
>   'xxx.IOViewController' (0x107f019a0)."

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func monthlyIncomeAction(_ sender: Any) {
    numberForSegue = 1
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "outcomeSegue", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func MonthlyOutcomeAction(_ sender: Any) {
    numberForSegue = 2
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "incomeSegue", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: (Any)?) {
    let ioController = segue.destination as! IOViewController
    ioController.segueIndex = numberForSegue
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is class of current controller and what are classes of 2 destinations controller?

Comment: @trungduc did you mean the name of the classes?

Comment: Yes ). Name of the UIViewController classes

Comment: @trungduc Current class is:"askForPlanViewController", the 2 destinations class are the same:"IOViewController"

Comment: What is `goalInfoViewController` class? Where you use it?

Comment: @trungduc It is the class where I just wanted a button to jump to without passing data

Comment: I have added an answer, please take a look

Comment: @trungduc Thx I will try it tomorrow

Comment: Please leave a comment on my answer if you can fix it so i can know you fixed it ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure only two segue which are to pass data between views can run code inside `prepare` method. Let's try the code below for `prepare` method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: (Any)?) {
    if segue.identifier == "outcomeSegue" || segue.identifier == "incomeSegue" {
      return;
    }

    let ioController = segue.destination as! IOViewController
    ioController.segueIndex = numberForSegue
}
```

Or

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: (Any)?) {
    if segue.destination is IOViewController {
        let ioController = segue.destination as! IOViewController
        ioController.segueIndex = numberForSegue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the second one, it worked as I expected ;)

Comment: Welcome @DifengChen ;)